# V5 Modal & jQuery: the issue in spinner while content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to display a spinner instigator while modal content is loading using **bootstrap v5 modal** and **jQuery** I create an example but it has some issues.

The spinner instigator not displaying again while I closed the modal it displays only in the first time.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  if ($(".modal").length) {
    $(".modal").modal("show");
    
    $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(".spinner").length) {
        $(".spinner").delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      }
    });
    
    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(e) {
      $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(".spinner").length) {
          $(".spinner").delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
        }
      });
      
      $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(".spinner").length) {
          $(".spinner").delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

**Live Example:** https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/oNWeYzp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `$(this).remove()` - removes the spinner completely. So the spinner element won't be available on the modal shown again.
2. Unnecessary code and conditions removed

**Solution**

Instead of removing the spinner element just hide it using the `d-none` class

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/PomKpWJ?editors=0010)**

```
$(function () {
  $(".modal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $(".spinner")
      .removeClass("d-none")
      .delay(3000)
      .fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).addClass("d-none");
      });
  }).modal("show");
});
```

Comment: how about displaying modal when page loading?

Comment: @Angusdev Its already displaying modal when page loading

Comment: no, I'm talking about when I visit the page the first time the modal displaying without clicking on button after I closing it I can open it by clicking on the button

Comment: try to see my example https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/oNWeYzp

Comment: @Angusdev Check the answer properly. there is a codepen link